# Control AppleTV 4K volume on monitor with speakers

Tags: audio, appletv, hdmi

Equipment:

- Apple TV 4K
- [iiyama ProLite E2273HDS](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0050T07R2/ref=pe_385721_37986871_TE_item) LED monitor, with built-in speakers
- iPad Pro
- iPhone 6S

Connection:

- HDMI, from Apple TV to monitor

I am temporaily using my Apple TV 4K with a computer monitor, instead of a conventional TV - connected via HDMI.

It's working great, except that **the only way I've found to control the volume of the built-in speakers is via the very fiddly on-screen menu**.

**Is there an easy way via the Apple TV to control the sound volume on a computer monitor with built-in monitors, without using the monitor's on-screen menu?**

Things I've tried:

- Using the volume control on the Apple Tv's remote - it tells me to use the remove control for my TV, which doesn't exist
- Use AirPlay or Screen Mirroring on iPhone and iPad to send to AppleTV - the iOS devices then don't allow the volume to be changed
- Search online for inline HDMI devices to control volume - I didn't find anything

Comment: I ended up connecting a Bluetooth speaker to the AppleTV - which (a) gave massively better sound quality than that of the monitor (b) allowed volume to be controlled by the AppleTV remote.

If I were choosing now, I would also consider a HomePod Mini, for less money, better sound quality, and more convenient connecting to  iPhones and iPads.

Comment: Volume control happens over HDMI-CEC which both ends must support.  If your monitor doesn't the Apple-TV has no way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easier way from the AppleTV or similar. In modern HDMI based systems the volume control always happens at the destination (for example the TV). When you send the audio digitally, the source (Apple TV) is not amplifying an analog signal and thus has no impact on the actual volume except for any external control signals it can.

Your computer monitor is probably not designed for use as a TV, and does not support receiving volume control signals anyway other than the on-screen menu. According to its manual, there doesn't seem to be any remote controls available or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2021 you can do this with a similar device. Google's 3rd gen Chromecast (and perhaps earlier models) supports this with an option to have the Google TV remote (as they call their remote) control the output volume level of the Chromecast, and hence the audio sent to monitor over HDMI. I found this option easily during Chromecast setup with a 32"/QHD Dell monitor and didn't need to consult documentation.

So this is an Apple feature omission. I just received the new 4K Apple TV and went to set it to behave the same way as the Chromecast and discovered that it is not supported. Shame on Apple for not supporting something so simple and helpful. Being able to double up a monitor as a TV is a nice feature in a lot of settings.

Edit: It's worth mentioning that the Chromecast will even connect to your Apple account and stream video content from it. (No Apple games or fitness routines, but not bad for the price. Kudos to Google, and I guess Apple, for enabling this integration.)

Comment: Thanks, but how does that help with controlling the volume of an Apple TV? I’m not seeing a link... If there’s no link, it would be better changed to a comment....

Comment: Sorry I couldn't solve the problem using an Apple TV, but neither could the accepted answer. No one can. There is however a solution (as of 2021) if you are prepared to switch to Chromecast. It will even connect to your Apple account and play Apple video content (but not games, Fitness+ routines etc). The accepted answer does not reflect this, and implies HDMI makes it impossible. That's incorrect. This is an Apple TV limitation. Having been burnt by Apple on this I'd like to alert as many people as possible to the (much cheaper) alternative that doesn't have this flaw.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I’ve removed the down-vote, as I appreciate the intention that your comment might help others in their buying decisions, even though the answer to buy different hardware does not help with my situation…